# Fragment BMP image by 8x8 blocks

Tags: c, image, image-processing

I'm writing a BMP image parser, I wrote the read and write functions, which works fine while reading B&W, grayscale, and color images. I'm writing a function for fragment a given image in 8x8 pixel images, so, if I have a 72x48 image, I will have 56 images. I already crop the pixels block, but when I write the images, these images have colors that the original didn't have, or are completely black.

[image]

The original image, the first 8x8 fragment, the second (the rest of the fragments are equals to this) 8x8 fragment.

I'm pretty confused because I already can read and copy the original image and write a copy.

Also, I crop an 8x8 fragment with a web tool, and some headers differ from the header that I calc. For example, the size of the whole file, which appears next to the image type is 172, while I calc 92. The header size is also different.

In order to fragment the image, I calc the number of fragments by multiplying the number of row by the number of columns, then I allocate memory for a list of images, where the fragments are saved, then I start a 3 nested for loop, where the first one is for allocated every image in the list and is jointed to the fragment number, the second and the third one is dedicated to copy pixel by pixel from the original to the block.

Could someone give a hint of what I could be doing wrong?

`bmp.h`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef uint16_t ImageType;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t size;
    uint16_t additionalFeature;
    uint16_t copy;
    uint32_t offset;

} ImageHeader;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t headerSize;
    int width;
    int height;
    uint16_t colorSpaces;
    uint16_t bitsPerPixel;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t size;
    int verticalResolution;
    int horizontalResolution;
    uint32_t totalColors;
    uint32_t importantColors;
} ImageMetadata;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t reserved;
} ImageColor;

typedef ImageColor *ImageColors;
typedef char *ImagePixels;

typedef struct
{
    ImageType type;
    ImageHeader header;
    ImageMetadata metadata;
    ImageColors colors;
    ImagePixels pixels;
} Image;

ImageType BMP_IMAGE_TYPE = 0x4D42;

unsigned int getImagePixelsSize(int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel);
unsigned int getImageSize(Image image);

void readImage(char *filename, Image *image);
void writeImage(char *filename, Image image);

void fragmentImage(Image image, Image *images, int fragmentWidth, int fragmentHeight);

void showImage(Image image);
```

`bmp.c`

```c
#include "bmp.h"

unsigned int getImagePixelsSize(int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel)
{
    return height * (int)(((bitsPerPixel * width) + 31) / 32) * 4;
}

unsigned int getImageSize(Image image)
{
    return (
        getImagePixelsSize(image.metadata.width, image.metadata.height, image.metadata.bitsPerPixel) +
        sizeof(image.type) +
        sizeof(image.header) +
        sizeof(image.metadata) +
        sizeof(image.colors)
    );
}

void showImage(Image image)
{
    printf("Size: %d \n", image.header.size);
    printf("Offset: %d", image.header.offset);
    printf("Width: %d \n", image.metadata.width);
    printf("Height: %d \n", image.metadata.height);
    printf("BPP: %d \n", image.metadata.bitsPerPixel);
    printf("Header size: %d \n", image.metadata.headerSize);
    printf("Total colors: %d \n", image.metadata.totalColors);
    printf("Raw colors: %lu \n", sizeof(image.colors));
    printf("Pixel size %d \n", getImagePixelsSize(image.metadata.width, image.metadata.height, image.metadata.bitsPerPixel));
    printf("Calculated Image Size: %d \n", getImageSize(image));
}

void readImage(char *filename, Image *image)
{
    FILE *imageFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!imageFile)
    {
        perror("ReadImageFileException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(&(image->type), sizeof(ImageType), 1, imageFile);
    if (image->type != BMP_IMAGE_TYPE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%hu", image->type);
        perror("ReadImageTypeException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(&(image->header), sizeof(ImageHeader), 1, imageFile);
    fread(&(image->metadata), sizeof(ImageMetadata), 1, imageFile);

    if (image->metadata.bitsPerPixel <= 8)
    {
        image->colors = (ImageColor *)malloc(sizeof(ImageColor) * image->metadata.totalColors);
        printf("Calculated raw colors %lu", sizeof(ImageColor) * image->metadata.totalColors); 
        fread(image->colors, sizeof(ImageColor) * image->metadata.totalColors, 1, imageFile);
    }

    int pixelsSize = getImagePixelsSize(image->metadata.width, image->metadata.height, image->metadata.bitsPerPixel);
    image->pixels = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * pixelsSize);
    if (!image->pixels)
    {
        perror("ReadImagePixelsException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(imageFile, image->header.offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(image->pixels, sizeof(char) * pixelsSize, 1, imageFile);

    fclose(imageFile);
}

void writeImage(char *filename, Image image)
{
    FILE *imageFile = fopen(filename, "w+");
    if (!imageFile)
    {
        perror("WriteImageFileException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int typeWritten = fwrite(&(image.type), sizeof(ImageType), 1, imageFile);
    if (typeWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageTypeException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int headerWritten = fwrite(&(image.header), sizeof(ImageHeader), 1, imageFile);
    if (headerWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageHeaderException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int metadataWritten = fwrite(&(image.metadata), sizeof(ImageMetadata), 1, imageFile);
    if (metadataWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageMetadataException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (image.metadata.bitsPerPixel <= 8)
    {
        int colorsWritten = fwrite(image.colors, sizeof(ImageColor) * image.metadata.totalColors, 1, imageFile);
        if (colorsWritten == 0)
        {
            perror("WriteImageColorException");
            fclose(imageFile);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    int pixelsSize = getImagePixelsSize(image.metadata.width, image.metadata.height, image.metadata.bitsPerPixel);
    int pixelsWritten = fwrite(image.pixels, sizeof(char) * pixelsSize, 1, imageFile);
    if (pixelsWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImagePixelsException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fclose(imageFile);
}

void fragmentImage(Image image, Image *images, int fragmentWidth, int fragmentHeight)
{
    if (fragmentWidth > image.metadata.width)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FragmentSizeException: Fragment width is larger than image width");
    }

    if (fragmentHeight > image.metadata.height)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FragmentSizeException: Fragment height is larger than image width");
    }

    int rows = (int)(image.metadata.width / fragmentWidth);
    int columns = (int)(image.metadata.height / fragmentHeight);
    int fragments = rows * columns;
    // 72 x 48 -> 8x8
    // 54

    // images[54]
    images = (Image *)malloc(sizeof(Image) * fragments);
    if (!images)
    {
        perror("FragmentImageMemoryException");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int w = 0, h = 0;
    for (int fragment = 0; fragment < fragments; fragment++)
    {

        (images + fragment)->type = image.type;
        (images + fragment)->colors = image.colors;
        (images + fragment)->header = image.header;
        (images + fragment)->metadata = image.metadata;

        (images + fragment)->metadata.width = fragmentWidth;
        (images + fragment)->metadata.height = fragmentHeight;

        int pixelsSize = getImagePixelsSize(fragmentWidth, fragmentHeight, image.metadata.bitsPerPixel);
        (images + fragment)->pixels = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * pixelsSize);
        if (!(images + fragment)->pixels)
        {
            perror("FragmentImageMemoryException");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++, w++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++, h++)
            {
                (images + fragment)->pixels[(w * 8) + k] = image.pixels[(w * image.metadata.width) + k];
            }
        }
        
        (images + fragment)->header.size = getImageSize(*(images + fragment));

        char *filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * 38);
        snprintf(filename, 38, "./images/fragments/fragment-%d.bmp", fragment);
        writeImage(filename, *(images + fragment));
    }
}
```

main.c

```c
#include "bmp.c"
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Image image;
    Image *images;

    char *imageSourceName = argv[1];
    char *imageTargeName = argv[2];

    readImage(imageSourceName, &image);
    writeImage(imageTargeName, image);
    showImage(image);
    fragmentImage(image, images, 8, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include "bmp.c"` do you mean `#include "bmp.h"`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm including in a correct way the header in both files